# Box-Muller method for correlated normals

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The standard Box-Muller method produces two independent normal variables given two uniform ones. Is it possible to extend the method such that given a correlation coefficient $\rho\in[-1, 1]$ and two independent uniform random variables it produces to standard normal random variables, but with correlation $\rho$?

I am aware that the most common way to get correlated normal random variables is to get independent ones first and then multiply them by the square root of the correlation matrix. At this time I am seeking an alternative approach though.

Comment: Is there a reason you are seeking an alternative approach?

Comment: What @Rahul asked. Especially in view of the fact that "the square root of the correlation matrix" is actually quite simple to write down as a function of $\rho$.

Comment: @Rahul, in my application I am generating around 150 correlated random variables many times, and then I am using a small subset. The requirement is that the generation is 'consistent', which means that given the seed for the random generation algorithm I will always produce exactly the same numbers. My end goal is to be able to consistently generate my subset of numbers without generating all 150 and discarding most of them (because it is slow).

Comment: On a side comment, I never understand why people on this site always downvote questions just because they are exploring a non-standard approach...

Comment: I still don't see why you couldn't do exactly the same thing with uncorrelated variables and then multiply by a matrix, but I won't pester you about it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it finally [in this paper.](http://www.survo.fi/papers/two_formulas.pdf)

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be independent uniforms on $(0, 1)$. Then the standard Box-Muller algorithm tells us that the random variables:

$$
V_1 = \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \cos(2\pi U_1)
$$
$$
V_2 = \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \sin(2\pi U_1)
$$
are independent $N(0, 1)$. Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be correlated normals:
$$
W_1 = V_1
$$
$$
W_2 = \rho V_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} V_2
$$

Then using the definitions above we get:
$$
W_1 = \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \cos(2\pi U_1)
$$
and
$$\require{enclose}
W_1 = \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \left[\rho\cos(2\pi U_1) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\sin(2\pi U_1)\right]\\
\enclose{horizontalstrike}{=  \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \left[\sin(\arcsin \rho)\cos(2\pi U_1) \cos(\arccos \rho)\sin(2\pi U_1) \right]}\\
=  \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \left[\sin(\arcsin \rho)\cos(2\pi U_1) + \cos(\arcsin \rho)\sin(2\pi U_1) \right]\\
= \sqrt{-2 \log U_2} \sin(2\pi U_1 + \arcsin \rho)
$$

Comment: Your $\begin{bmatrix} W_1 \\ W_2\end{bmatrix} $ is equal to     $  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ \rho &  \sqrt{1-\rho^2}\end{bmatrix} \, \begin{bmatrix} V_1 \\ V_2\end{bmatrix} $. That looks just like the matrix multiplication suggested in the comments by @Rahul. Can you clarify how this is different (as in alternative non-standard)?